# push notification (GCM using Andriod) working fine in Local host but failed to work in production server

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I have used `Push` notification in my web application using **asp.net webforms**.
That `Push` notification works fine in my Localhost connecting live Database but failed to work in Production Server.

What can be the Issue ?

Do i Need to make changes in my webConfig file?????

Please Suggest

```html
    public static void CallPUshNotiFication(string Msg,string EmailId,string PageName)
        {
            try
            {
                
                DataSet dsregID = new DataSet();

                StringBuilder strBldId = new StringBuilder();

               
                var applicationID = Validate.ApplicationId;
                var SENDER_ID = Validate.SenderId;


                List<MobileRegistration11> PuschList = MobileRegistrationManager1.GetDataFromMobileRegistration1(EmailId);
                if (PuschList.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in PuschList)
                    {
                       

                        string regId = Convert.ToString(item.RegistrationId);
                        
                        WebRequest tRequest;
                        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                        //
                        tRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        tRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
                        tRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                        tRequest.Method = "post";
                        //
                        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
                        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
                        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
                       
                        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
                            + Msg + "&registration_id=" + regId + "&data.id=" + PageName+ "&data.recordId="+147+"";

                        
                        Console.WriteLine(postData);
                        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                        dataStream.Close();
                        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
                        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                        strBldId.Append(sResponseFromServer + "<br>"); //printing response from GCM server.
                        tReader.Close();
                        dataStream.Close();
                        tResponse.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I you have access to your machine, then try running this on command line.

Replace your topic and key. You may need to install curl.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: key=<PUT your key>" -d '{

   "condition": "'"'"'<Put your topic>' in topics",
  "data": {
    "payload": ""
   }
}
' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

If this is giving proper response, then we can be certain that your machine is able to access GCM server. Then we can move to other things.

Thanks

Comment: i got the solution, actually the mistake was in this part time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1  ,i have set both to 1 ,now i am receiving it properly...thanks for the help anyway :)